# Temperature change in adiabatic free expansion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, adiabatic

Consider a gas with fixed number of particles $N$ undergoing adiabatic free expansion from $V_1$ to $V_2$.

Apparently we have the following relation
$$\Delta T=T_2-T_1=-\int_{V_1}^{V_2}\frac{dV}{C_V}\left[ T\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial T}\right)_{V,N} -p \right]$$

So,

$$\begin{align}\Delta T=T_2-T_1 &=\int^2_1 dT  \\
&=\int^2_1\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_{E,N}dV+\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial E}\right)_{V,N}dE+\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial N}\right)_{E,V}dN \\
&=\int^2_1\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_{E,N}dV
\end{align}$$

Now I cannot see how $\left(\frac{\partial T}{\partial V}\right)_{E,N}$ can be evaluated. I have the expression $S=\frac{1}{T}(E+pV-\mu N)$, but as $S$ is function of a few variables I dont see how this can be used.

Comment: Note: $E$ may denoted $U$ elsewhere